# Free space in the bottom of the Div-element

Tags: html, css, css-position

[image]

I create "Thanks"-page. In the main part of the page i put

and .
According to the design, the bottom picture should overlap the button and paragraph, and in order to achieve this I adjust:

```
position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 250px;
    z-index: 0;
```

to the image.
As a result, the picture got into the right position, but in the bottom remain free space in parent  element.
How to remove this free space and why did it appear.

I'll try to move img in the different parts of code.

Comment: an image is an inline-element (treated as an inline-block). As such it has an inline descender space for letters such as y, g, j, p, and q. To remove that descender space you need to turn the image into a block level element with: `display: block;`

Comment: Please edit your question and use the snippet tool `<>`